# How to open a ssh connection using pxssh module in python

Tags: python, ssh

i want to open a ssh connection from one server to another,so trying to use pxssh module for this.
I am getting the following error while running the below code:

My Code:

```
import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh()
if not s.login ('host','user','password'):
    print "SSH session failed on login."
else:
    print "SSH session login successful"
    s.sendline ('ls -ltr')
    s.logout()
```

On running this code i am getting the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh.py", line 20, in <module>
    if not s.login ('135.250.138.207','astro','astro'):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pxssh.py", line 243, in login
    if not self.synch_original_prompt():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pxssh.py", line 134, in synch_original_prompt
    self.read_nonblocking(size=10000,timeout=1) # GAS: Clear out the cache before getting the prompt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 824, in read_nonblocking
    raise TIMEOUT ('Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().')
pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
```

How can i successfully run the above code?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.sendline()
```

add this before line 134,
in File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pxssh.py" 
and it works as expected.